# How can I enable, scan, and disable windows defender from inside a scheduled task?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, scheduled-task

If windows defender is disabled can you later (through a script) enable, run a scan and then disable it via a powershell script that is invoked as part of the scheduler?

If this is possible then figuring out a way to email problems will be the next hurdle.

This is within a windows 2016 server environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this should be possible with powershell on Windows Server 2016.

Commands obtained from technet (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn433280(v=wps.630).aspx)

Please see the below.

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $false
Start-MpScan -ScanType FullScan
$Report = Get-MpThreat | ConvertTo-Html
If ($Report -ne $null){
    Send-MailMessage -From <SenderAddress> -to <RecipientAddress> -SmtpServer <SMTPServer> -Subject "Defender Report" -Body $Report 
}
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
```

I can confirm that the scan works and the real time monitoring gets disabled, however as my WS2016 environment is clean I am unable to test the report.

This can be saved as a ps1 file and used in task scheduler.

Things that could have an impact is other anti-virus suites disable and prevent defender from being enabled, eset being an example.

hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks CraftyB. I will test this and get back to you.